# How to get options of choosing between windows 8 and ubuntu at start up?

Tags: 13.04, windows-8, startup

I installed Ubuntu 13.10 alongside windows 8.1 in a separate partition.
But on start up , windows 8.1 automatically boots without giving me options to choose between windows and Ubuntu.
Plz help! I want to choose OS on start up!

Comment: This is confusing: Have you installed 13.10 or 13.04?

Answer (score 1):

If you still have your Ubuntu disk with you, try booting from that and run `grub-install /dev/sdX` where X is the device letter for the hard drive that contains both Windows 8 and Ubuntu partitions, in a Terminal session.